# iTunes crashes quickly after opening, every time

Tags: itunes, crash

I'm running iTunes 12.6.0.100 and MacOS 10.2.3 on a late 2015 iMac. Every time I open iTunes, whether with a brand new local library or an external drive library I've had for several years, the app crashes. It doesn't throw an error or anything, it just closes. I've tried, of course, opening it without a library to create a new one, and also booting in safe mode. Neither of these have helped. I've also tried reinstalling iTunes itself.

I do have iTunes Match on my account, but am not an Apple Music user.

I read somewhere that I could try clearing out the iBooks library, and so I tried this. At first I thought it might be helping, as it took a little while for it to crash, but it still crashed. There does seem to be some inconsistency in how long it takes to crash when it opens, but this doesn't appear to be related to anything I do differently.

What might be happening, and what additional things could I try?

Comment: Is it still happening if you iTunes with no internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is quite an old question but I encountered this issue myself and managed to solve it, so I'm answering in case it helps someone (maybe even the OP). I am on Windows machine but perhaps it's the same solution on Mac as well(in some cases).

First I narrowed down the problem to be related to the internet connection. I disconnected from the internet and the crash no longer occurred when having internet connection.

I updated the network and chipset drivers [(as this article explained)](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203206) but the crash still occurred.

Ultimately, I connected to a wireless hotspot only to see the crash no longer happens, so I understood that the problem was the way I connected to the internet.

Since I was behind a corporate proxy, changing the proxy server fixed the issue